# Should this question be closed as a duplicate and how to give it an answer for future viewers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60748277/1193647) on SO, which was closed as a duplicate of another question. In the process of trying to explain and come up with reasoning as for why it's not a duplicate, I managed to track down the answer to the original question.

From a duplicate viewpoint, my question is trying to figure out the discrepancy between what I was seeing in VS2019 and Unity. It wasn't related to the problematic code found in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41288668/1193647).

In fact, if someone sees the same issue that I did, and decides to go to the linked question, they'll find that the "problematic" code works exactly as my question describes.

Lastly, the linked question isn't related to Unity.

Trying to understand this, I did end up figuring out the reason for what I'm seeing (though maybe not the entire underlying cause).

VS2019 is seeing `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` in the csproj file and trying to apply C# 8.0 features, which [allows specifically the code that I wrote](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/shadowing-in-nested-functions.md). .Net Standard 2.0 is listed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) as pointing to C# 7.3, which doesn't support the feature, which explains why Unity and the person who closed the question are seeing errors in their compilation. (No idea why my Unity project defaults to C#8).  But again, I feel like this answer is significantly different than the linked question, pointing to them being different issues.

I would like to know what's the best way to update the question in case someone else runs into with the issue that I described: should I just tack the answer on to the bottom of the question, or try to get the duplicate unlinked and provide a self-answer (or some other course of action).

Comment: Since you know that 7.3 (like targeting .NET Core 2.2 in VS 2019) does not support it and 8 (targeting .NET Core 3.x in VS2019) supports shadowing maybe you should ask actual question - "why Unity does not use C#8 and use C#7.x instead"... For many people the way you asked question is backward (as non-latest versions  did not allow shadowing) - so expecting behavior that many people don't expect is confusing... Also linking unrelated example of local variable shadowing the class variable was not necessary.

Comment: If I really wanted to create self-answered question on this topic I'd ask new one instead "Local variable in nested functions hiding one in outer scope  - some projects  CS0136, some pass" and answer with C#7.3 vs C# 8 along with some ideas what targets use which version of C#... Easier than getting duplicate re-opened... (also now it likely get re-opened - so you can edit it instead)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's reasonable, but at the time I didn't know that the project was using c# 8 (or even that this was something introduced in 8 as opposed to 7). Based on what you said, would you create a separate question, or just edit this one to shift the focus on the language mismatch as you pointed out. Based on how I read the other duplicate questions on meta, it seems editing is the preferred way?

Comment: I didn't ask many (3) questions yet, so can't advice much... I would ask a new question linking to the previous one to avoid re-open process (if I'm confident that I can actually write a proper question for it - writing the question for a self-answered post is *hard*) . If you want the original question re-opened than indeed edit is the way to do so (likely editing of the existing question is easier than writing a new one) - it likely get enough visibility with this meta post... You can also just add comment/answer to the duplicate, also that one is c#7.x specific right now.